# How to pass arguments to the function without binding in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So, i've readed that doing something like this

`<SomeButton onPress={() => { this.someFunction(args)}} />`

is bad because it is creating a new instance of function for each render cycle.

But how do i pass args in React-Native then?

Comment: Have you tried `<SomeButton onPress={this.someFunction.bind(this, args)} />`?

Comment: Is not this the same thing?

Comment: Oh you are right, this also creates a new function on every render. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new inline function is fine in many cases, but if you have a lot of `SomeButton` components it might be worth passing the `args` as props to the component and use that as arguments in the component's `onPress` instead.

**Example**

```js
class SomeButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const { onClick, someProp } = this.props;
    onClick(someProp);
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick = arg => {
    console.log(arg);
  };

  render() {
    return <SomeButton onClick={this.handleClick} someProp="foo" />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`HTML data-* Attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

**someFunction**

```
someFunction= (event)=>{
  console.log(event.target.dataset.mykey )
}
```

**render:**

```
<Button data-mykey onPress={this.someFunction} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In which context? I would say it depends if that is what you want or need to have. In general you could use properties instead of passing arguments.

I guess you read something about re-rendering (which may result in loss of performance); here is what is said about it in the react-native guide:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation